# Changed Array to Arraylist so that I can manipulate the Array

Tags: java, android

got a few problem here and hoping that you could help me out.

Let me first clarify the situation:

I have a static array of Integer in which inside was a R.drawable.images. Codes are as follows

```
private   Integer[] imageIDs = {
            //R.drawable.medal_my_first_perxtamp,
            R.drawable.medal..._gray,
            R.drawable.medal_y...te_me_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_t...ring_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_gi...ray,
            R.drawable.medal_a..._gray,
            R.drawable.medal_se..gray,
            R.drawable.medal_p...._gray,
            R.drawable.medal_m..._gray,
            R.drawable.medal_lo.._gray,
            R.drawable.m..._gray,
            R.drawable.med..,
            R.drawable.med..on_gray
          };
```

Now what I am trying to do is change the value of imageIDs based on a condition so now ive added this code on getview

```
       sqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(mContext);
        sqlAdapter.openToRead();
        List<Integer> imageIDList = Arrays.asList(imageIDs);
        String query2="Select achievementID  from achievementdata_tb where memberID = 101";
        Cursor cursor2 =sqlAdapter.read(query2);
        if (cursor2 != null && cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
            while(cursor2.moveToNext()){

                val =cursor2.getString(0);
                int val2 = Integer.parseInt(val);
                String returnDrawable = getDrawables(val);
                int intReturnDrawable = Integer.parseInt(returnDrawable);
                imageIDList.set(val2, intReturnDrawable);
            }
        }
```

Note that I am getting values from database(achievement_ID) and the values is (6,2,3)

So what I did is get the cursor's item one by one and check it on a public void **getDrawables** consist of

```
        public String getDrawables(String str){
        if (str.equals("3")){
            str= "R.drawable.med...g";
        }
        else if (str.equals("2")){
            str= "R.drawable.med..._me";
        }
        else if (str.equals("6")){
            str= "R.drawable.me...._up";
        }
        return str; 
    }
```

See that I want to change the value of array imageIDs (which is a drawable) to another drawable image.

I dont have any error so I use debugger and found out that I am getting an error on this part **int intReturnDrawable = Integer.parseInt(returnDrawable);**

I am new to andriod but i know some basic functionalities..
Could you help me solve this out?

Comment: why not cursor.getInt(0) instead of getString and parseInt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because, the **return type** of `getDrawable()` is **String**. And the String like `"R.drawable.med...g"` can't parse to `Integer`.

So change the implementation of `getDrawable()` return proper `int` value ..

Instead do something like,

```
public int getDrawables(String str){
        int value = 0;
        if (str.equals("3")){
            value = R.drawable.med...g;
        }
        else if (str.equals("2")){
            value = R.drawable.med..._me;
        }
        else if (str.equals("6")){
           value = R.drawable.me...._up;
        }
        return value; 
    }
```

Comment: I see I thought that I could just convert it again to int

Comment: So then these toe lines  `String returnDrawable = getDrawables(val);
                int intReturnDrawable = Integer.parseInt(returnDrawable);`
 becomes one `int intReturnDrawable = getDrawables(val);`

Answer (score 0):

The statement will throw an error

```
int intReturnDrawable = Integer.parseInt(returnDrawable);
```

when `returnDrawable` is a String which can not be parsed into an integer; which is your case.

Since when you call `getDrawables()` it returns `"R.drawable.med..._me"` which is not an integer.

You can modify `getDrawables` like:

```
public Integer getDrawables(String str){
    if (str.equals("3")){
        return R.drawable.med...g;            
    }
    else if (str.equals("2")){
        return R.drawable.med..._me;
    }
    else if (str.equals("6")){
        return R.drawable.me...._up;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: obvious answer is obvious. Paraphrased: you are getting an error while parsing a string to an int because your string cannot be parsed to an int.

Answer (score 0):

R.id.drawable1 is an integer, and "R.id.drawable1" is a String which can not be parsed to an Integer. Why are you getting String from integer, than integer from String, instead you can get integer directly from the method getDrawable();

```
 public String getDrawables(String str){
        int result;
        if (str.equals("3")){
            result= R.drawable.med...g;
        }
        else if (str.equals("2")){
            result= R.drawable.med..._me;
        }
        else if (str.equals("6")){
            result= R.drawable.me...._up;
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

and change accessing of this image to following:

```
sqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(mContext);
        sqlAdapter.openToRead();
        List<Integer> imageIDList = Arrays.asList(imageIDs);
        String query2="Select achievementID  from achievementdata_tb where memberID = 101";
        Cursor cursor2 =sqlAdapter.read(query2);
        if (cursor2 != null && cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
            while(cursor2.moveToNext()){

                val =cursor2.getString(0);
                int val2 = Integer.parseInt(val);
                int intReturnDrawable = getDrawables(val);
                imageIDList.set(val2, intReturnDrawable);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`"R.drawable.med...g"` is not an `int`. You cannot parse it. you can only parse values like `"0"`, `"-3"` ...

in `getDrawables`, return an `int`, like `R.drawable.med...g` (no quotes) and use it as such.